# Counting values in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, count, row

I have a mySql database and I have a question about counting several values with the same "Provider_id". Let me explain it as simple as possible. I have 3 rows: Provider_id (No unique values at end of text), click_count(How many clicks on their site, int value) and logo_id(This one is the same as Provider_id so they could be connected). "Provider_id" and "click_count" are in the same table and logo_id is from a different table. I want to match "Provider_id" and "Logo_id" and want to count click_count with the matching Provider_id.

For example:

> (table 1)
>
> Provider_id = 102    click_count = 10
>
> Provider_id = 102    click_count = 22
>
> (table 2)
>
> logo_id = 102
>
> -- What I want to get --
>
> Provider_id = 102    click_count = 32

Could anyone help me with this?

Explained Provider_id:

There are unique website id's in the table with Provider_id so the Provider_id doens't have to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) both tables and do [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) Provider_id and taking the sum of click_count will solve the problem.So try like this

```
select t1.Provider_id,sum(t1.click_count) from table_1 as t1 
inner join table_2 as t2 on t1.Provider_id = t2.logo_id 
group by t1.Provider_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` statement and group by Provider_id:

```
SELECT b.logo_id, SUM(a.click_count) AS click_count 
FROM table_1 AS a LEFT JOIN table_2 AS b ON a.Provider_id = b.logo_id
WHERE b.logo_id = 102
GROUP BY a.Provider_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT    `field`,
          count(*) as `count`
```

or

```
SELECT    `field`,
          SUM(`counter`) as `total`
```

together with

```
GROUP BY `field`
```

and don't forget to make INDEX(`field`) (or better INDEX(`field`, `counter`))